# How to avoid manual cleanup when using baggage with Spring Cloud Sleuth and MDC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have several Spring Boot + Sleuth 2.1 based micro services (A, B and C) that make HTTP requests from one to another (A->B->C). I'm using Sleuth to pass additional parameter 'x-session-id' (baggage) between the applications as HTTP request header and use SLF4J to log the value of the parameter in log statements. For this I have configured in application.yml:

```
spring.sleuth:
  propagation-keys:
    - x-session-id
  log:
    slf4j:
      whitelisted-mdc-keys: x-session-id
```

And in logback-spring.xml the pattern value is:

```
%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [xSessionId=%X{x-session-id:-},traceId=%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}] [%thread] %logger : %m%n
```

Everything works when I set the HTTP header "x-session-id" externally (so I make request to A with header x-session-id and the value is automatically passed from A to B and from B to C). So the value moves between applications and appears on log statements of each application.

But when I generate the value of x-session-id inside the application (let's say inside A) and set the value to Sleuth programmatically (instead of passing it as HTTP request header) then the header is added to outgoing requests normally but SLF4J doesn't know about it and log statements don't show out the value. This is how I make Sleuth aware (I @Autowire tracer):

```
Span continuedSpan = tracer.toSpan(span.context());
ExtraFieldPropagation.set(continuedSpan.context(), "x-session-id", "mySession123");
```

However when I explicitly pass the value to MDC like this:

```
org.slf4.MDC.put("x-session-id", "mySession123");
```

then it stays with the thread even after the request completes and I have to clean it up manually. For this I have created separate interceptor:

```
@Component
public class CleanupBaggageInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CleanupBaggageInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, @Nullable ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        logger.debug("Cleaning up any baggage that has manually been set to MDC");
        MDC.clear();
    }

}
```

and registered the interceptor with the app:

```
@Configuration
public class MidGatewayConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CleanupBaggageInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Is there any way to set the baggage value to Sleuth in a way that Sleuth itself sets it to MDC (and cleans it up after the request the same way it cleans up traceId)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've added the mdc as a whitelisted key, whenever the scope is closed we automatically remove the entry from mdc. Have you debugged the Slf4jScopeDecorator to confirm that this is happening? In general the answer is such that whenever the scope is closed we clear all the mdc context including the entries from the whitelisted keys

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Slf4jScopeDecorator debugging showed that in the beginning of the request whitelistedBaggageKeysWithValue and whitelistedPropagationKeysWithValue are stored (into previousMdc list) and after the request only those (that had a value) are removed from MDC. Since I don't pass the baggage as a request header (I set it during processing of the request) then it doesn't get removed in the end. I wonder I should open a feature request to enable adding baggage during the processing of the request in a way that it would get cleaned up after processing of the request.

Comment: Yeah, why not. Please create an issue and describe your problem with your analysis and the expected outcome. Let's discuss it there :)

Comment: Awesome. I created the issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1416 Let's continue discussion there.